# Error al organizar elementos traidos de una base de datos a travez de javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy realizando un to-do-list con la ayuda de ajax, tengo dos columnas una de *tareas pendientes* y otra de *tareas completadas*, en mi base datos tengo un campo llamado *completed* el cual tiene como posibles valores de 0 en caso de no estar completada ó 1 en caso de que la tarea este completa.
En mi archivo *ajax.js* con ayuda de un if trato de colocar las tareas que están en mi base de datos en sus columnas correspondientes. pero ahi viene el problema ya que las tareas pendientes de alguna manera también se colocan en la columna de *tareas completadas*, el código es el siguiente:

```
 function getData() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'libs/get-tasks.php',
      type: 'GET',
      success: (response) => {
         let data = JSON.parse(response);
            let template = '';
            data.forEach(task => {
               template += `
               <div class="card">
                  <h2>${task.name}</h2>
                  <p>${task.description}</p>
                  <div class="footer">
                     <p id="date">${task.date}</p>
                     <div class="actions">
                        <span class="icon-thumb_up"></span>
                        <span class="icon-mode_edit"></span>
                        <span class="icon-delete"></span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>`;
               console.log(task.completed);
               if(task.completed == "0"){
                  $('#pending-tasks').html(template);
               }else if(task.completed == "1"){
                  $('#completed-tasks').html(template);
               }
            });
      }
   });
}
```

Les dejo una captura para que quede más claro
[image: El error que veo es que las tareas pendientes estan duplicadas, ya que las tareas completadas están en su columna como debe ser]

Comment: lo que pasa es que estas concatenando tu variable template con el template +=, ademas de eso estas haciando un $().html() lo que hace esto que remplace todo tu html por uno elemento. La solucion seria que quites el += por el =... quedaria asi let template =, tambien que quites el html por el append... quedaria asi $('#pending-tasks').append(template);

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, muchas gracias, no me había percatado de esos detalles

Comment: Que bueno poder haberte ayudado. saludos.